# Is Saxon susceptible to XXE attacks?

Tags: saxon

When we load an XML file to then make XPath 2.0 queries on it, [will an XXE file in the XML be processed?](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/band-xml-external-entity-oob-xxe/)

And if so, is there any way to turn that off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XXE is an XML parser vulnerability and Saxon does not do XML parsing itself, it invokes whatever parser you configure it to use (there are defaults of course). You have full control over what XML parser Saxon uses and how that parser is configured. Details depend on what platform and API you are using.